# How to implement an enum case with 'OR"?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code:

```kotlin
enum class Items {
  ITEM_1,
  ITEM_2,
}
```

I want to add:

- `AT_LEAST_ONE` that is somehow equal `ITEM_1 or ITEM_2`
- `ALL` that means `ITEM_1 and ITEM_2`

**Use case 1:** when i use `if (item == Items.AT_LEAST_ONE)` it want it to actually means `if (item == Items.ITEM_1 || item ==Items.ITEM_2)`

**Use case 2:** when I am using them as arguments in a function:`calling_function(ALL)` instead of `calling_function( Items.ITEM_1,Items.ITEM_2)`

Is there a way to do it in Kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is not supported. There is no such thing as an enum constant that is a collection of other enum constants.

However, enum classes can have functions, so perhaps you can use that to achieve what you want:

```
enum class Items {

    ITEM_1,
    ITEM_2;

    fun isFoo(): Boolean =
        this == ITEM_1 || this == ITEM_2
}
```

Now you can call `if (item.isFoo())`, rather than the proposed `if (item == Items.ITEM_3)`.

Comment: What if I have a function that calls all of them. Now I am using `calling_function(listOf(Items.ITEM_1,Items.ITEM_2))`. I want to be  able to use something like `calling_function(Items.ALL))`

Comment: You could use `Items.values()` to get an `Array<Items>` containing each enum constant. Or you could use `EnumSet.allOf(Items::class.java)` to get an `EnumSet<Items>` "containing" each enum constant. The first is more likely to be what you want, but the second is useful in certain situations.

Answer (score 1):

Like Ben says, enums don't work that way - every member is a distinct object instance, so `Item3` has to be a concrete, unique thing, not a logical concept that represents other objects.

If you like though, you can get similar functionality to enums with sealed classes, and you can create a type hierarchy with those:

```
sealed class Items {
    sealed class AT_LEAST_ONE : Items() {
        // objects because there should be one, singleton instance of each
        object ITEM_1 : AT_LEAST_ONE()
        object ITEM_2 : AT_LEAST_ONE()
    }
}

println("ITEM_1 is an Items: ${ITEM_1 is Items}")
println("ITEM_1 is AT_LEAST_ONE: ${ITEM_1 is AT_LEAST_ONE}")

> ITEM_1 is an Items: true
> ITEM_1 is AT_LEAST_ONE: true
```

You don't actually need to nest them if you don't want, the hierarchy is based on the supertypes in the constructor. So you can create your own groups for things, give them multiple types with interfaces if you like!

```
// no nesting, Items is the supertype, multiple types for some
interface Special
interface AT_LEAST_ONE

sealed class Items
object ITEM_1 : Items(), AT_LEAST_ONE, Special
object ITEM_2 : Items(), AT_LEAST_ONE

// casting because otherwise the compiler knows "is" will fail and complains
println("ITEM_2 is special: ${(ITEM_2 as Any) is Special}")
println("ITEM_1 is special: ${(ITEM_1 as Any) is Special}")

> ITEM_2 is special: false
> ITEM_1 is special: true
```

Only thing is it's not an enum so the different `object`s aren't **enum**erated, so if you needed that you'd have to sort it out yourself. As far as I know there's no equivalent to the `values()` method in enums either, even though the compiler is aware of all the types (so it can check pattern matching is exhaustive)

Answer (score 0):

You can try add abstract function to enum class for extra condition

I try like this :

```
enum class Items {
    ITEM_1 {
        override fun calculate(item: Items): Boolean = item == ITEM_1
    },
    ITEM_2 {
        override fun calculate(item: Items): Boolean = item == ITEM_2
    },
    //AT_LEAST_ONE only for check
    AT_LEAST_ONE {
        override fun calculate(item: Items): Boolean = item == ITEM_1 || item == ITEM_2
    },
    //ALL only for check
    ALL {
        override fun calculate(item: Items): Boolean = item == ITEM_1 && item == ITEM_2
    };

    abstract fun calculate(item:Items): Boolean

    enum class GetItem{
        ALL{
            override fun get(): List<Items> {
                return listOf(ITEM_1,ITEM_2)
            }
        };

        abstract fun get(): List<Items>
    }
}
```

and use for that enum class like this :

```
    Log.e("ENUM TEST", "TEST ITEM_1 : (item == ITEM_1) ${Items.ITEM_1 == Items.ITEM_1}")
    Log.e("ENUM TEST", "TEST ITEM_2 : (item == ITEM_2) ${Items.ITEM_2 == Items.ITEM_2}")
    Log.e("ENUM TEST", "TEST AT_LEAST_ONE : (item == AT_LEAST_ONE) ${Items.AT_LEAST_ONE.calculate(Items.ITEM_1)}")
    Log.e("ENUM TEST", "TEST ALL : (item == ALL) ${Items.ALL.calculate(Items.ITEM_1)}")
    Log.e("ENUM TEST", "TEST ALL : (ALL == ALL) ${Items.ALL == Items.ALL}")
    Log.e("ENUM TEST", "TEST ALL : (ALL == listOf(ITEM_1, ITEM_2) ${Items.GetItem.ALL.get().size}")
```

Answer (score 0):

To specifically deal with the use cases:

> Use case 1: when i use if (item == Items.AT_LEAST_ONE) it want it to actually means if (item == Items.ITEM_1 || item ==Items.ITEM_2)

1. You can write this as `item is Items` without adding anything.
2. If you want literally `item == Items.AT_LEAST_ONE`, you'd have to override `equals` in an `enum class` which is not supported.
3. You *could* try to get `Items.AT_LEAST_ONE == item` by defining

   ```
   object AT_LEAST_ONE {
       override fun equals(other: Any?) = other is Items
   }
   ```

   but it actually doesn't work; Kotlin sees `AT_LEAST_ONE` and `Items` are unrelated types and refuses to compile `AT_LEAST_ONE == Items.ITEM1`. If it did work, it would violate the contract for equality by not being symmetric.

> Use case 2: when I am using them as arguments in a function:calling_function(ALL) instead of calling_function( Items.ITEM_1,Items.ITEM_2)

In another comment you have

> calling_function(listOf(Items.ITEM_1,Items.ITEM_2))

instead; but again, you don't need to add anything for it and just write

```
calling_function(Items.values().toList())
```

if you want to achieve `calling_function( Items.ITEM_1,Items.ITEM_2)` in particular and it's a `varargs` function, write it as

```
calling_function(*Items.values())
```